# coppy ds_list item to variable in GameMaker

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

```
function foo(_bar) constructor
{
    bar = _bar;
}

__foo = ds_list_create();

ds_list_add(__foo, new foo(5));

__bar = __foo[| 0];

__bar.bar++;


show_debug_message(string(__foo[| 0].bar));

show_debug_message(string(__bar.bar));
```

And I have in Output:

```
6

6
```

How I can `__bar` and `__foo[| 0]` as Difference, I want to `__bar.bar = 6` and `__foo[| 0].bar = 5` (default).

Comment: Just a guesswork coming [from the internet](https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/copy-an-array-instead-of-passing-by-reference.20460/#post-324088), try `__bar = __bar;` before `__bar.bar++;`.

Comment: I tried your method and it didn't work